# Private Sorting Rule in a Stream Java

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, collect

Hey if anyone has an idea I would be really thankfull.
I'm in a Java stream and i would like to sort my list that i'll be returning.
I need to sort the list via TradPrefis ( MyObject::getTradPrefix ).
But this would be way too easy. Because i want to sort following the number at the end of TradPrefix exampleTradPrefix_[NUMBER TO SORT]

Exemple :         hello_1
                  test_2
                  ...
                  still_there_22

Here is a piece of code so you can imagine easier.

```
public LinkedHashSet<WsQuestion> get(String quizId, String companyId) {
    LinkedHashSet<QuizQuestionWithQuestion> toReturn = quizQuestionRepository.findAllQuizQuestionWithQuestionByQuizId(quizId);
    return (toReturn.stream()
            .map(this::createWsQuestion)
            .sorted(comparing(WsQuestion::getTradPrefix.toString().length()))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I where you I would simply put a method on the `WsQuestion` class, let's call it sort order:

```
public int getSortOrder() {
  return Integer.valueOf(tradPrefix.substring(tradPrefix.lastIndexOf("_") + 1));
}
```

The `Integer` parse is needed since comparing strings would give *"11" < "2"* (thanks [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for pointing this out). The `lastIndexOf()` makes sure that any number of underscores are allowed in `tradPrefix`, as long as there is at least one.

Then simply create a comparotor by using [`Comparator.comparingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction))

```
public LinkedHashSet<WsQuestion> get(String quizId, String companyId) {
  LinkedHashSet<QuizQuestionWithQuestion> toReturn = quizQuestionRepository.findAllQuizQuestionWithQuestionByQuizId(quizId);
  return (toReturn.stream()
      .map(this::createWsQuestion)
      .sorted(comparingInt(WsQuestion::getSortOrder))
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)));
}
```

Comment: Since the numbers in the example are in the range 1 to 22, parsing the string *is* needed, as when comparing strings, `"11" < "2"`. You can only skip parsing to int when you can preclude differently sized strings and leading zeros or when you add special handling for these cases.

Comment: @Holger Of course, forgot to think about that scenario. I updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

One method would simply be to split `getTradPrefix().toString()` by `_` and parse the rightmost value as an `int`, and use it to sort the `Stream`:

```
public LinkedHashSet<WsQuestion> get(String quizId, String companyId) {
    LinkedHashSet<QuizQuestionWithQuestion> toReturn = quizQuestionRepository.findAllQuizQuestionWithQuestionByQuizId(quizId);
    return toReturn.stream()
        .map(this::createWsQuestion)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(question -> {
            String[] args = question.getTradPrefix().toString().split("_");
            return Integer.parseInt(args[args.length - 1]);
        }))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
}
```

Comment: What about "still_there_22"?

Comment: i guess that i'll just have to change the return Integer.parseInt(args[1]); to 
return Integer.parseInt(args[args.length - 1]);

Comment: Don’t use `.split("_")` to populate an array when you are only interested in the last element. You can use `.replaceFirst(".*_", "")`, for example, to only get the part after the last `_`. With that, you could even make it a one liner again.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a small `Comparator` like this:

```
  private static final Comparator<String> questionComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(s -> {
    String[] pieces = s.split("_");
    return Integer.parseInt(pieces[pieces.length-1]);
  });
```

Then use it in your `sorted()`.

Having a separate Comparator will make your code more readable too, since you will be separating concerns.

```
return toReturn.stream()
            .map(this::createWsQuestion)
            .sorted(questionComparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```